# Can I return Boolean value in a loop statement?

Tags: java

I just came up with a problem returning a Boolean value in accordance with a given condition. I thought in order to check the given condition for **full possibilities** I need to use **for loop**. But when I tried to compile it, it gives me error, possibly because there is **uncertainty** returning a Boolean value using for loop. Here is an original problem:

```
Return true if the given string contains a "bob" string, but where the middle 'o' char can be any char. 

bobThere("abcbob") → true
bobThere("b9b") → true
bobThere("bac") → false
```

And here is my code:

```
    public boolean bobThere(String str) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<str.length()-3; i++)
        {
            if (str.length()>=4): && str.charAt(i)=='b' && str.charAt(i+2)=='b') 
            {
                return true;
            }
            else 
                return false;
            else if (str.length()==4 && str.charAt(0)=='b' && str.charAt(2)=='b') 
            {
                return true; 
            } 
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I just wanted to ask :
1. Can I fix the this code for returning a value. I mean, can I use for loop and return specific value for a given condition? If yes, please could you give me a sample. 
2. Or are there any ways other than for loop to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what's the reported error?!   (and no, there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to return a boolean inside a loop)

Comment: You have an `if-else` followed by an `else-if else`. Which is wrong. Please go through basic java control strcutures

Comment: There are various problems with this. To start with: a) what if you never enter the loop body? b) you've got an `else if` after a plain `else` - that's invalid; what did you expect it to mean? c) You appear to be trying to return from *every iteration* of the loop. I suspect you don't want to.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Here is a code:

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP needs to understand how control structures work in JAVA.

Comment: public boolean bobThere(String str) 
{
  for(int i=0; i<str.length()-3; i++)
 {
    if (str.length()>=4): && str.charAt(i)=='b' && str.charAt(i+2)=='b') 
      {
       return true;
      }
      else 
      return false;
    else if (str.length()==4 && str.charAt(0)=='b' && str.charAt(2)=='b') 
     {
       return true; 
     } 
    else
     {
       return false;
     }
}
}

Comment: @S.Dovra - 1. Please don't post answers as comments. 2. Please explain what the code is about

Comment: OK. Sorry for doing that. My bad. I think I found an answer and understood what is wrong with doing. I forgot to include "break". Thanks for your time and sorry for any misunderstandings I caused.

Comment: Parse full string instead of a part. One more loop is needed to challenge the state of the condition.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes, the OP has made an effort to ask a question covering the difficulty they have.

Comment: @NickJ - This question has been closed because the OP needs to understand how `if-else` has to be used not because this seems trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler error is almost certainly because you have an `elseif` after an `else`. That's invalid.

Looking at your code, what you seem to want to do is loop through the string, and then return `true` if you're at the start of a `b?b` string. I'm not sure why you have your second `if` condition in there - at the moment your code would check the first and third characters of the string on *every iteration* of the loop, if the string happens to be exactly four characters long. Pointless, it doesn't need to be there. The check for length isn't necessary at all.

Additionally, your end condition for the loop is currently `i < string.length()-3`. This means that the final three characters of the string will not be checked. You would need to change this to either `i <= string.length()-3` or `i < string.length()-2` to solve this.

Your `else return false` stuff is going to give you a serious problem. Your code will enter the loop once, and then either return true or false, without ever going to the next phase of the loop. What you should do is loop through the string, and if you find what you're looking for, return `true`. Otherwise, don't return at all, and keep going with the loop. If you get to the end of the loop it means you never found what you were looking for, so you can at that point return `false`.

Taking those comments into account, your revised code would look like this (please note I haven't compiled or run this):

```
public boolean bobThere(String str) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 3; i++)
    {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'b' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'b') 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You did a great job man! Thank you. What is good is that my stupid brain could be able to understand it :).